# Soma de count's de diferentes colunas

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia, possuo uma atividade escolar na qual tenho o objetivo desenvolver as consultas *sql's* referentes a cada questão. A atividade tem 1000 resultados da megasena, contendo as colunas `sorteio`, `data_sorteio`, `dezena1`, `dezena2`, `dezena3`, `dezena4`, `dezena5` e `dezena6`. Uma das questões é "Qual foi a bola mais sorteada?"

```
SELECT COUNT(dezena5), dezena5 as bola FROM megasena
GROUP BY dezena
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(dezena6), dezena6 as bola FROM megasena
GROUP BY dezena6;
```

Como por exemplo a *bola 1* pode aparecer em todas as dezenas, tenho que somar quantas vezes ela apareceu em cada dezena, e depois todas?
E como apresento somente a que mais apareceu?

Comment: Você disse "a bola 1 pode aparecer em todas as dezenas", de onde exatamente você tira esse dado? As "dezenas" são os números?

Comment: Sim, a dezena são os numero. Segue um print que pode ajudar: https://prnt.sc/116ikbt .

Comment: man, tava tentando mexer um pouco no código mas acho que aí você teria consultas diferentes, não? ou seja, seria uma única consulta pra trazer **total por dezena**, **total geral** e **a que mais apareceu**, ou seriam consultas diferentes?

Comment: A resposta tem que ser a quantidade de vezes que a bola apareceu e qual foi a bola que mais apareceu, ou seja, tenho que realizar a contagem de cada bola em cada dezena e depois somar a contagem para bolas iguais, e apresentar dentre essas bolas qual foi a que tem a contagem maior.

Comment: Eu estou sem tem para escrever uma resposta detalhada e documentada, mas veja uma solução aqui https://paiza.io/projects/uhYZVnH3pYVdoUhshBBQ7g?language=mysql

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso!!!

Answer (score 0):

A resposta é a seguinte:

1. Unifique o valor de todas as dezenas, mas ao invés de UNION utilize UNION ALL, pois o UNION quando há repetições considera uma única vez o valor, lembra das aulas de teoria de conjuntos A U B? Banco de dados é teoria de conjuntos :) https://www.todamateria.com.br/teoria-dos-conjuntos/
2. Dê um alias (apelido), para a coluna dezena1 do primeiro select, porque fazendo isso ele se transformará no nome da coluna, que representará os valores gerados através das UNIONS, ou seja, só ela precisa de um apelido;
3. Aplique o count(*), agrupando através do campo "bola", resultado das UNIONS;
4. Ordene o resultado do count(*) de cada bola por ordem decrescente (Maior para o menor);
5. Por fim limite o resultado;

Esse formato é legal porque deixa sua query mais flexível, manipulando o limit, você poderia retornar por exemplo as 5 bolas mais sorteadas, as 10+ e etc...

Espero ter ajudado, e se ganhar na mega-sena, espero receber um PIX :)

```
  
  select bola, count(*) numero_vezez
    from (
    SELECT dezena1 as bola
     FROM megasena
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT dezena2
     FROM megasena
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dezena3
     FROM megasena
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dezena4
     FROM megasena
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dezena5
     FROM megasena
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dezena6
     FROM megasena
    ) bola
    group by bola
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1
```